# Python Importing In-between Folders

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

Before-hand Note: This is being applied to my files in Python 3.6.0, however any solution in the Python 3.x field is good-to-go!

## Importing in-between Folders

I'm currently on Windows (not that it matters) and holstering a directory-system as seen:

```
Python Projects (Irrelevant)
+- Some Project (Irrelevant)
+- Some other abandoned Project (Irrelevant)
|
| (Some space to put some thought on perspectives...)
|
+- Current Project
    +- game.py             <-(acting as a game-launcher)
    +- __init__.py         <-(for packaging purposes)
    +- main                <-(folder)
        +- menu.py
        +- __init__.py
        +- chapters        <-(folder)
            +- chap1a.py   <-(Irrelevant)
    +- misc                <-(folder)
        +- func.py
        +- __init__.py
```

I've been experimenting with several importing methods, ranging from:
1. the `__import__` method itself
2. placing *all* the files in one folder and importing between them (which *does work*, but I'm looking for a more 'Pythonic' method of doing it)
3. performing relative imports and readjusting `sys.path` to guide the import process
4. using `from <whatever folder> import <file>`
5. using `from <file> import <class or function>` (which works, but I can't get past the 'between folders' problem)
6. placing `__all__ = ["filename", "filename"]` in the `__init__.py`'s
7. importing with the `folder.folder.file <attribute?>` syntax

... and many more methods which have ultimately failed me. (Perhaps I'm not quite *that* lucky?)

## A little more in-depth (what I have tried...)

My original importing method, used when all my work was originally programmed in Python 2.7 and based on a Raspberry Pi (ah, old memories), consisted of:
- Placing `__init__.py`'s in all my sub-folders then importing like: `import main.menu`
- Additionally using Specifics when Importing: `from misc.func import <function>`
- Placing all the files in one folder *then* importing (that was when I moved to folder-importing, as a means to make things neater)

The above had worked splendidly. But... now that the syntax (and standards) is a bit different, you may be able to see my trouble.

I have tried appending the path that the import process would take:

```
#Python
import sys
sys.path.append("/Current Folder/main/menu.py") #Example
import menu
```

, to receive `NameError`s or `ModuleNotFoundError`s:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\~\Documents\PythonProjects\CurrentProject\game.py", line 11, in <module>
  import menu
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'menu'
```

I am now having to expand upon individual function-imports, turning them into folder imports (staying far away from wild-card importing). An example would be the `game.py` file, which (hypothetically)uses: `import main.menu` and `import misc.func`.

This 'weird' folder-naming convention of mine also leads to the question of:

**What's all this being used for?**

The User will begin the game by executing the `game.py` file (or a Windows / Mac Executable), which imports from the 'misc' folder: `func.py`, and from 'main': `menu.py`.
The Game-launcher hands over control to the Main-menu file, which displays (you got it!) the Main Menu. If the user quits, it'll perform `sys.exit(0)`. If they play the game however, it'll *then* import-and-play a `chap.py` file (chapter file).
Once that specific chapter file is finished, it will presumably hand back control to the `menu.py` which will *then* give the option of quitting or playing further chapter files.

Mind boggling, I know. If anyone has a better solution than to what I've been doing for the last four months - please enlighten me, I need an update to my **"Knowledge-bank"** desperately.
Thank you.

Comment: Most of the things you tried should have worked fine, although not all of them would be a good idea. You must be doing something wrong you haven't shown us. Show us specific failing code and tell us specifically how it fails, including full error message and stack trace if there is one.

Comment: Also, nothing about this setup is special or uniquely distinct from the giant pile of other Python import questions.

Comment: @user2357112
My 'failing code' isn't available now - as I had the 'absolutely great idea' of deleting it, to then replace it with what I'd learn or take from here. But I can edit my post to display in-depth what I have done.

Comment: Then write up a super-simple example, test it, and show us that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the specific attempt you showed us:

```
#Python
import sys
sys.path.append("/Current Folder/main/menu.py") #Example
import menu
```

The Right Thing would be to do `import main.menu` and use things from that module as `main.menu.whatever`, or `from main import menu` and use `menu.whatever`, rather than messing with `sys.path`.

---

As for why what you tried didn't work, `sys.path` doesn't work like that. It lists the *folders* whose contents Python searches for modules, not the files or folders that themselves implement modules. If you had put `.../main` instead of `.../main/menu.py` on the path, the `import menu` would have succeeded.

However, messing with `sys.path` that way has all sorts of other nasty consequences that you really don't want to deal with, especially if you don't yet have the knowledge to use regular imports correctly. You don't want to end up with 3 independent, subtly different copies of the same module, created from the same file, or all the other horrors of screwing up your `sys.path`. Don't do it.

Comment: To your First Part... if I were to wrap the entirety of my main menu file into a function then call it from the game-launcher: that would work, right?
As you say that I can do `main.menu.<function>`. If so, cool.

Comment: I've been experimenting for a couple days (yes, it's taken me that long) and I seem to have cracked it - turns out that wrapping everything in a function and doing a call does it. Thanks!